# C# Lambda Functions: returning data

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, anonymous-function, lambda

Am I missing something or is it not possible to return a value from a lambda function such as..

`Object test = () => { return new Object(); };`

or

`string test = () => { return "hello"; };`

I get a build error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type".

It's like this syntax assigns the lambda rather than the result of the lambda, which I did not expect.
I can achieve the desired functionality by assigning the function to a Func and calling it by name, but is that the only way?

Please no "why would you need to do this?" regarding my example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @IAbstract Your edit completely changed the question so I rolled it back.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: odd ... I was *attempting* to remove the last 2 lines. Thanks for catching that. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value with anonymous method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520892/how-to-return-value-with-anonymous-method)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It’s possible but you are trying to assign a lambda to a `string`. – You need to *invoke* the lambda:

```
Func<string> f = () => { return "hello"; };
string test = f();
```

The error message actually says it all:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string'

… that’s exactly the issue here.

If you want to invoke the lambda inline – but really: *why*? – you can do that too, you just need to first make it into a delegate explicitly:

```
string test = (new Func<string>(() => { return "hello"; }))();
```

Comment: Assigning a lambda expression to an implicitly-typed variable will not work.

Comment: @DominicKexel Ah, very true.

Comment: Ah that was quick. was just editing my question when you answered. Is it possible to Invoke the lambda inline rather than assigning to a Func<string>?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Konrad. And because I have a nice wide screen and like to write lines like:

`_queuePath = new Func<string>(() => { if (Directory.Exists(currentLineSplit[1])) { return currentLineSplit[1]; } else { throw new Exception("Queue path does not exist."); } })();`

Comment: @DrewR why not just use the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)? `_queuePath = (Directory.Exists(currentLineSplit[1])) ? currentLineSplit[1] : throw new Exception("Queue path does not exist.");`