# C# - How to return value with anonymous method?

Tags: c#

This code fails:

```
    public bool generateNewIdentity()
    {
        TCPClient torIdentityClient = new TCPClient();

        torIdentityClient.OnConnect += delegate ()
        {
            torIdentityClient.Write("AUTHENTICATE \"*********************************\"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n");
        };

        torIdentityClient.OnRead += delegate (TCPClient tcpClient, string[] dataReadArray)
        {
            if(dataReadArray[0] == "250 OK")
            {
                return true;
            }
        };

        torIdentityClient.Delimiter = "\r\n";
        torIdentityClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9151);
    }
```

It's being returned a string array containing `["250 OK", "250 OK"]`

The exception it is giving me is `Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value`.

I am trying to make it return true, if it gets 250 OK.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to return true? and who is going to handle the value true?

Comment: I want it to be returned from OnRead to generateNewIdentity, so it can ran like so bool isSuccess = generateNewIdentity();

Comment: Could you post an answer showing how I wound do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value with anonymous method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520892/how-to-return-value-with-anonymous-method)