# Feature 'inferred delegate type' is not available in C# 9.0

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, c#-10.0

I'm trying to write the following code:

```cs
var name = "Kyle";
var sayHello = () => $"Hello, {name}";
Console.WriteLine(sayHello());
```

But I get the error:

```
Feature 'inferred delegate type' is not available in C# 9.0.
```

What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

#### Problem

The problem is the actual [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) itself `() => $"Hello, {name}"` does not actually have a type (*yet*).

It is only typed once it's cast to either:

- A [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) of type [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-6.0) or [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-6.0)
- Or an [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) of type [`Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-6.0) (which can then be compiled to a delegate)

#### Solution in C#10

[C#10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10) made several [lambda improvements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/lambda-improvements) including an [inferred delegate type](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/expressions.md#1116-anonymous-function-expressions), meaning C# can now determine (infer) that the lambda is going to be used as a delegate function - so the original syntax is available upon **upgrade to C#10**:

```cs
var sayHello = () => $"Hello, {name}";
```

#### Previous Solutions

If you can't upgrade to C#10, there are a couple ways you can explicitly type the lambda.

You can provide an explicit type instead of using `var`:

```cs
Func<string> sayHello = () => $"Hello, {name}";
```

Or you can use the func constructor to type the expression:

```cs
var sayHello = new Func<string>(() => $"Hello, {name}");
```

[**Demo in .NetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nhcZmb)

#### Further Reading

- [delegate keyword vs. lambda notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299703/1366033)
- [How to return value with anonymous method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10520892/1366033)